# Stack Snippets full page view always shows scrollbars

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Here is an example:

```html
<h1>This is the only element on the page</h1>
```

When you open a code snippet in full page view you will notice that the vertical scrollbar is there even though there is nothing to scroll. (Corollary: if the content is tall and vertical scrollbar is required then you will notice two vertical scrollbars). This is a usability issue. Suppose you are reading this question and you perform the following actions:

1. Click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button
2. Click the <kbd>Full page</kbd> button
3. Scroll the page using the vertical scrollbar, mouse wheel or keyboard
4. Click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button

You will end up in the middle (or possibly at the end) of the page, not where you left off.

Comment: I think rather than "Full page" they should just label it as "Expand" and not take up the entire page. Make it more like a popup that takes up the *majority* of the page while still having some discernible spacing/margin around the box to indicate it's *not* a new page and that it's just a closeable popup box. I think the way it's currently displayed is confusing, and the Close button is very unnoticeable over in the corner.

Comment: I don't know if I want animuson's idea or the one as posted in the question... so I upvoted both... I'm such a bad person :(

Comment: Possible solution: hide everything else on the page except the iframe and the scrollbar will disappear.

Comment: I just deleted the `iframe` element from the page and realized it's the page underneath that is scrolling. And after deletion "Run Code Snippet" always results in a new tab (using Chrome), which... I kinda like.

Comment: @SalmanA Instead of hiding everything, one could also just set overflow: hidden on the body (or something along the lines, don’t beat me for the details). I did this for a projetc, and at least in firefox it did exactly what I wanted: the scroll position was kept intact, one could even jump to anchors, but the scrollbar vanished. The iframes scrollbar should be taking precedence in that case if it is present.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: yup. Your suggestion works as expected.

Comment: @Krumia: `target` attribute ahoy!

Comment: Give me some consensus. Do we want full page and no scrollbars, or @animuson's pop-up idea?

Comment: @Haney Add each option as an answer (with a mockup?) and let the voting commence?

Comment: So @Haney gets all the upvotes? :p

Comment: @SalmanA - no score is given on meta sites other than meta.stackexchange.com so don't worry - I don't benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @Haney You'll benefit from the knowledge of which idea users like more. :) Doesn't that count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for suggesting this change. I have checked in code that eliminates page scrolling when Stack Snippets are viewed in full screen. I chose this approach over a "pop-up" style approach because I feel that maximizing the screen space is an essential feature of Stack Snippets. It allows you to show that a pixel is truly at position 0,0 for example. This will be live in the next build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.23.2595`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.23.1883`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is much of a usability issue. The inner window scrolls if needed, and the outer frame scrolls too, that is the default behavior, while it may seem a bit unintuitive at first, sealing the user's scroll while the window is active changes the default behavior.

So it scrolls, so what? At the end of the day, it's a fixed div. I expect the page to scroll underneath.